# Disabling Optimus / Graphics cards

Tags: nvidia, battery, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

I have a Dell XPS 15 L502x. I using Ubuntu 14.04 duel booted with window 7. I looking to get more life out of my battery while in Ubuntu. I have no need for the nvdia card while using Ubuntu since this is where I do my work.

What I would like to know is if this guide on this [Page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15) can be applied to 14.04 since it makes no mention of this version in the list and if so will it benefit my battery by disabling the nvidia card?

also to note I have not installed any drivers I'm using a the ones that ubuntu installed during the OS installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying it can't do any harm.

Use the following command before and after the switch. >ou should see a drop/rise in mW being used:

```
# grep rate /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
```

switch off your NVIDIA card using

```
# echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

If your laptop now uses less mW, then you get a longer battery life.

Comment: I used the above and the changes are 1460 mA 1456 mA. So it doesn't look like it helps that much. I went ahead and did the permanent fix but it doesn't look like it did what it was supposed to because the echo on and grep rate still show i can reduce the power usage to what i stated above.

Comment: I'd have expected a more important drop in power consumption, but then again, perhaps the optimus wasn't running under high load before.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a NVIDIA binary driver (you can check by searching for the Additional Drivers program and looking at which driver is selected), then you can use the Nvidia X server settings to change which gpu is used. To launch the Nvidia X server settings, either search for "Nvidia" in the dock or launch the program from the terminal using "nvidia-settings". There will be a tab that allows you to select the correct gpu (sorry, I don't know which one exactly).