# Disable nVidia graph card

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, asus, bumblebee

I have a Asus with 2 graph cards - 1 nVidia and 1 Intel - and my battery life is being shortened because I THINK both gpu are being used by Ubuntu. I tried some called **Bumblebee** but or I configured it wrong or it didn't work.

Any idea on how to do this? I've seen other posts but none of them worked. Sorry for any mistake but english is not my main language.

PC : [Specs](http://www.asus.com/au/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55VJ/specifications/)

Ubuntu version : 14.04

[UPDATE]
So I followed what was suggest in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04) in an answer and everything went well. I can't run optirun for some reason ( it never detects my secondary GPU ) and so I'm still working on that.

Comment: I asked something like this a few days ago. My goal was to disable my nvida card and just use the intel card. you can take a look at my question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/520587/disabling-optimus-graphics-cards

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. 
I tried both of the code suggested on your topic and the code suggested in the page you mentioned.

Battery life is at 1h40min .

Comment: I'm not sure if bumblebee would inhibit the changes suggested in that guide.